# linq and operator issue

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

i have query of linq to sql like this

```
  forms = attributesData.Where(x => x.strValue.ToLower().Contains(ddlProvince.SelectedItem.Text.ToLower())
            && x.attributeName == "Province"
            && (x.attributeName=="District" && x.strValue==ddlDistrict.SelectedItem.Text)
            && (x.attributeName == "TrainingProgram Code" && x.strValue==ddlSearch.Text)
            && (x.attributeName == "Father Name" && x.strValue==txtform.Text)

            ).Select(t => t.strFormId).Distinct().ToList();
```

problem is i have only strvalue column in my DB which is stores every information now i have to apply multiples search operation if i apply and operator query return null.But if i apply or operator query return values but i need result of and operator not or operator please help.

Comment: You are using EAV. Are you using some sort of ItemId which is common for all attributes?

Comment: can u show me how you apply the OR operator?

Comment: in other words: update your question to include the query with the or operator.

Comment: hi my or condition is like this
 forms = attributesData.Where(x => x.strValue.ToLower().Contains(ddlProvince.SelectedItem.Text.ToLower())
                && x.attributeName == "Province"

             || (x.attributeName == "District" && x.strValue.ToLower().Contains(ddlDistrict.SelectedItem.Text.ToLower()))
               || (x.attributeName == "TrainingProgram Name" && x.strValue.ToLower().Contains(txtTrainingProgramName.Text.ToLower()))
                || (x.attributeName == "TrainingProgram Code" && x.strValue.ToLower().Contains(ddlSearch.Text.ToLower()))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question, it looks like you are using Entity Attribute value pattern. To filter the results using AND, you need to join the table to itself many times depending on the search criteria. It is a overhead associated with this pattern. Following is a sample code which addresses how joins can be handled in your scenario. In the example, I am assuming that the Entity Id which groups all the attributes together as "strFormId".

```
Dictionary<string, string> equalitySearchCriteria = new Dictionary<string, string>();
equalitySearchCriteria.Add("TrainingProgram Code", ddlSearch.Text);
equalitySearchCriteria.Add("District",ddlDistrict.SelectedItem.Text);
// Add other items

Dictionary<string, string> likeSearchCriteria = new Dictionary<string, string>();
likeSearchCriteria.Add("Province", ddlProvince.SelectedItem.Text.ToLower());
// Add other items

var query = attributesData.Where(x => true);

foreach(var criterion in equalitySearchCriteria)
{
   var equalityJoinQuery = attributesData.Where(x => x.attributeName == criterion.Key && x.strValue == criterion.Key);
   query = query.Join(equalityJoinQuery, x => x.strFormId, y => y.strFormId, (x, y) => x);
}

foreach(var criterion in likeSearchCriteria)
{
   var likeJoinQuery = attributesData.Where(x => x.attributeName == criterion.Key && x.strValue.Contains(criterion.Key));
   query = query.Join(likeJoinQuery, x => x.strFormId, y => y.strFormId, (x, y) => x);
}

var result = query.Select(t => t.strFormId).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply but i have error on
var query = attributesData.Where(x => x);

Comment: I guess you were getting error on variable declaration. I have updated the answer. I am typing the code using notepad. So could not check for compile time errors.

Comment: Yup Where() expects a boolean result. I have updated the answer. Try now please. That is just an example initialization query. You can have any common filter in this line.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words. Glad I could help.